# JOOQ transactions with DefaultTransactionProvider without functions

Tags: java, database, transactions, jooq

I'm aware that I can use `DefaultTransactionProvider` with `DSLContext` and lambdas like this

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .transaction(ctx -> {
       DSL.using(ctx)
          .update(TABLE)
          .set(TABLE.COL, newValue)
          .where(...)
          .execute();
});
```

However I would like to control my transaction outside the scope of a code block (but still using `DefaultTransactionProvider` as its behavior with checkpointing and such is what I'm looking for). More like this

```
configuration.transactionProvider().begin(transactionContext);
DSL.using(configuration)
    .update(TABLE)
    .set(TABLE.COL, newValue)
    .where(...)
    .execute();
configuration.transactionProvider().commit(transactionContext);
```

Is this possible or will I need to implement the transaction SPI myself to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.8, this is not possible out of the box. There is a pending feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5376

Your code will probably work:

```
configuration.transactionProvider().begin(transactionContext);
DSL.using(configuration)
   .update(TABLE)...
configuration.transactionProvider().commit(transactionContext);
```

But beware that you're calling SPI methods, not API methods. These methods have not been designed for direct access by you as an API consumer. They're designed for implementation and injection into the jOOQ SPI context in the `Configuration`. If you want to continue this path, your `TransactionProvider` will need to access the `Configuration.connectionProvider()` and modify its state in order to produce always the right connection until `commit()` or `rollback()` is called.

See also a related discussion on the jOOQ user group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jooq-user/1JwWMChD2SM/NHUhSnI8AgAJ

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on that feature.